# putting text file data into a hash map

Tags: java, java-io

my data in the text file looks like this...

```
3
movie title
4
movie title
1
movie title
```

the number on top is the movie rating and the text under it is the movie title.

The code I have so far is below. But It's not printing anything out except empty brackets! Sample code would be appreciated!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MovieReview {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sgoetz/Desktop/movieReviews.txt"));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(map);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are printing map on console not line

Comment: Is each film supposed to have a distinct rating? Why do you want a `Map<Integer, String>`?

Comment: Do you want to group the movies by rating in some kinde of list?

Comment: From your comment on Sarz's answer you want to determine the average rating for all movies in the text file, if that is the case then your format is subject for improvement. Did you define yourself or did predefied? It should define the movie then followed by its rating not the other way around. Nevertheless it is still feasible. Pleas consider editing your question to include what you want to do with the data in the text file, otherwise it is not easy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movieReviews.txt"));
            String line="";
            int i=0;
            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                map.put(i,line);
                i++;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<map.size();j++){
                System.out.println(map.get(j));
            }
        }
```

Comment: @user3320634 please vote up and mark it as accepted if this answer resolve your problem. see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: It reads every line as a film name, including the rating lines. The rating of the map are in fact sequential numbers. How can it work great?

Comment: how can i get it to output in a neater format? like "Movie Title: 3 reviews, average of 4.3/5? So some movies are in the list more than once because they got different ratings from different sources.

Comment: It reads every line from the file and put it in the Map. now its @user3320634 logic how to manage with this. he can also use comma separated string for this purpose also it saves the space and keep the map size equal to movies

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing nothing because you are printing the map on which you put nothing. So the map remains empty. Also your first while iteration is buggy, you read one line from the stream before the while loop then you enter it an immediately read the next line. The first line is lost.

For reading from a buffered stream the following pattern should be considered:

```
while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
    // do what ever you want with the line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store moving names of against its rating you have to declare map as Map>. Following code populates the movie title against its rating. Hope this is helpful.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieReview {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sgoetz/Desktop/movieReviews.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //Rating
                int rating = Integer.parseInt(line);

                //Movie name
                line = br.readLine();

                List<String> movieList = map.get(rating);

                if(movieList == null) {
                    movieList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    map.put(rating, movieList);
                }

                //Adding movie name to list
                movieList.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go 
File:

```
3,movie title,rating,other,other
4,movie title,rating,other,other
1,movie title,rating,other,other
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movieReviews.txt"));
            String line="";
            int i=0;
            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                map.put(i,line);
                i++;
            }
            String movieNumber="";
            String movieTitle="";
            String movieRating="";
            String movieOther1="";
            String movieOther2="";
            for(int j=0;j<map.size();j++){
                if(!(map.get(j)== null)){
                    String[] getData=map.get(j).toString().split("\\,");
                    movieNumber = getData[0];
                    movieTitle = getData[1];
                    movieRating = getData[2];
                    movieOther1 = getData[3];
                    movieOther2 = getData[4];
                    System.out.println("|"+movieNumber+"|"+movieTitle+"|"+movieRating+"|"+movieOther1+"|"+movieOther2);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more example:

```
while (true) {
    // Number line
    String value = br.readLine();
    if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    Integer valueInt = Integer.parseInt(value);

    // Name line
    String title = br.readLine();
    if (title == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }

    map.put(valueInt, title);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

And the output is:

```
{1=movie title, 3=movie title, 4=movie title}
```